# How to use a bundle that works with Java 1.7 in a project running 1.8?

Tags: java, maven, exception, osgi, bundle

My Maven project is running with Java 1.8 however used bundle execution environment is JavaSE-1.7. When I start the bundle following exception is occured.

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7

How to start this bundle without any exception? I can not change the Manifest file of the bundle.

Comment: This depends on the framework you use and how you set it up. You will have to explain a bit more how your framework is setup. All frameworks I know automatically provide this capability for backward compatible VMs.

Comment: I suspect you use an old equinox version. Maybe this version does not yet provide the correct capability for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that this would have been handled by the framework  default settings; if not, it should be possible to add the required execution environment / capability by changing an appropriate launch property-

> The org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment launching property defines the current execution environment with a comma separated list of execution environment names. If not set, the framework must provide an appropriate value. This property is also deprecated, its function is replaced with org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities[.extra].
>
> -- [OSGI Core Specification § 3.4.1](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.bree)

The relevant capability  is `osgi.ee`. See [OSGI Core Specification § 8.2](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.namespaces.html#framework.namespaces.osgi.ee) for details.

Comment: It may turn out that one of these changes was made, and did not include 1.8, in which case another approach might be to undo the customization and seeing if using  the defaults work.